# Dont display varaibile if it contains no value (PHP|

Tags: php, soap

I am using SOAP to get some data from other service, i get XML and convert and display it with PHP. The thing is sometimes there is no value for it in XML file and i dont know how to display some message like "This thing was not set", instead of that i am just getting notice with 
Notice: Array to string conversion in \data2.php on line 636
Array

What i tried:

```
                  if(isset($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']))
                  echo  var_dump($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']);
```

output: array(0) { }

After that i try something like:

```
                  if(isset($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']))
                  echo  var_dump(isset($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']));
```

Output: bool(true)

So it looks i am doing things bad, can you gimme some advise how can i fix it?

p.s. I know i can stop displaying errors and notices but its not the way how i want to "fix" it

Comment: use if (isset($var) && !empty($var)) { // code here }

Comment: Hi mate, your answer is right, Rakesh Sharma answer first the correct thing so i marked him answer as correct, thanks for help anyway ,nice knowleage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you no need to `echo` after `var_dump` already have `var_dump`(used for printing array) or may be you have not an array for `$claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']` it's a string

```
 var_dump($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']); // for array
 echo $claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc'] // for string
```

returning bool(true) cause you have `isset()`(will return boolean true/false)

```
var_dump(isset($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']));
```

For printing array values you only need :-

```
var_dump($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']); or var_dump($claim);
```

will return you complete array output

for any check empty values try

```
if(!empty($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']))
  var_dump($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise, you are right of course. But its not helping to fix display that notice.
`var_dump($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']);` return `array(0) { }`

Comment: try echo $claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']

Comment: Dear Rakesh Sharma it was echo which throw notice, but anyway your code with empty works perefectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply echo ing the message.

`if( ! isset($claim ['vehicle']['engine-cc']))

echo 'engine-cc - This thing was not set';`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use option "SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS" most likely.
By default SOAP returns empty or a single value for a SOAP attribute as a string, not an array. Adding option SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS into SOAP client request would force to return the value as an empty ARRAY rather than empty string. See [example here](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#103305).